# C++ pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed

Tags: c++, class, pointers, c++11

I'm trying to create an entity system.
  Each entity has a list of components and each component has a pointer to the parent Entity.

========================Example Code:=========================

```
---------------Dog.h--------------------
    #include <string>

    class AnimalCare;
    class Dog
    {
    public:
    Dog(AnimalCare* parent);

    std::string GetParentName();
    void Feed(void*);
    private:
    AnimalCare* g_parent;
    }
    ----------------------------------------

    ----------------Dog.cpp-----------------
    #include "Dog.h"

    Dog::Dog(AnimalCare* parent){
     g_parent =parent;
    }

    void Dog::Feed(void* food){
     //TODO: Feeding
    }

    std::string Dog::GetParentName(){
    [1]return parent->GetName();
    }
    ----------------------------------------

    ---------------AnimalCare.h-------------
    #include "Dog.h"

    class AnimalCare{
    public:
       AnimalCare(std::string name);

       std::string GetName();
       void InitDog();
    private:
       std:string g_name;
       Dog* g_dog;
    };
    ----------------------------------------

    --------------AnimalCare.cpp------------
    #include "AnimalCare.h"

    AnimalCare::AnimalCare(std::string name){
       g_name =name;}

    std:string AnimalCare::GetName(){
      return g_name;}

    void AnimalCare::InitDog(){
      g_dog = new Dog(this);}
```

============================================================

[1] -> I'm getting pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed.
I know, it is because AnimalCare class in Dog header is just declared but not defined. ->Is there a way to get around this?<-

Comment: You need to include `AnimalCare.h` in `Dog.cpp`.

Comment: i have tried that, it gave me a lot of errors...

Comment: Those errors will probably point you in the right direction. You should also not include `Dog.h` in `AnimalCare.h`: a forward declaration will do.

Comment: missing a semicolon ";" at the end of class Dog. Than include Dog.h in the .cpp.

Comment: In `Dog::GetParentName()` you `return parent->GetName();`. I don't understand why you're getting a "pointer to incomplete type" error; you should be getting an undefined symbol error. The member you probably meant to use was `g_parent`. Is the code you have put in the question the same as the code you are actually trying to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this to Dog.cpp:

```
#include "AnimalCare.h"
```

Also, you are missing the ; after your class declaration for Dog, so it should be:

```
class Dog
{
public:
Dog(AnimalCare* parent);

std::string GetParentName();
void Feed(void*);
private:
AnimalCare* g_parent;
};
```

Comment: Thank You :D, it was so simple. :( That was just an Example code. The actual code is a lot bigger.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes just needs a second pair of eyes to take a look. Please accept this answer if it solved your problem. Thanks